# how to delete a duplicate field in xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have a table with a column type XML, the xml files in that column has duplicate field which I want to remove. Please let me know how can I update that column accordingly.

```
<Material_NOI>
<Field> -------- ? I want to delete this duplicate one.
  <Field>
    <id>Type</id>
    <value>Initial</value>
    <tag />
    <visible>true</visible>
    <history>10/8/2015|</history>
    <description />
    </Field>
    </Field>
 </Material_NOI>
```

Comment: If `<Field>` is there twice, but the closing `</Field>` tag is there only once, you might think, that this is XML, but **this is not XML!!!** How is this generated?

Comment: Nice point from shnugo. This seems more like XML's syntax error than duplicate. Also even if the Field gets repeated you first need to identify how you define a value being duplicate. For that I suppose a good way would be to read to XML from DB do the manipulation and then update the new xml into the database. Typically you always need to define the metrics of dulicity.

Comment: Thanks nice catch. I missed it in the earlier post. Field is being generated twice. Currently i just want to delete it rather than running the whole xml again. Is it possible ?

Comment: interestingly you may see another post which shows up as related Q&A here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411401/sql-server-xml-type-column-duplicate-entry-detection?rq=1

Comment: based on the other discussion I will say no.

Comment: @wwidhoo Once again: How is this XML generated? If this is under your control, you should avoid the doubled `<Field>` there...

Comment: @wwidhoo Btw: Dates *within* XML should be ISO8601. You really should avoid culture specific date formats like `10/8/2015`! On one machine this is taken as 10th of August, another system would return with 8th of October... Other systems might break entirely...

Comment: @wwidhoo I just posted an update for table data...

Comment: Thanks Shnugo, I appreciate. I'll post the code soon which causing the duplicate.

Comment: @wwidhoo Please stick to SO's principle *One issue - One question*. If one of the existing answers solves **this** issue, please mark it as accepted, vote on all good or bad contributions and start a new question *How can I create the XML without the `<Field>` being doubled?*. Then place a link to this new question here. Thx

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Will do that. I really like your solutions provided.

Comment: @Shnugo, here is the link for the new question. I added the code that I was using to generate the XML. thanks  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497463/how-can-i-generate-a-xml-without-repeating-an-field-twice

Comment: @wwidhoo will have a look at it soon! If this is solved, it would be kind to choose one answer (the best for you) and tick the acceptance check below the vote counter. Voting and accepting are two separate steps. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest was to take the needed node with `.query()` and rebuild the XML

```
DECLARE @XML XML=
N'<Material_NOI>
  <Field>
    <Field>
      <id>Type</id>
      <value>Initial</value>
      <tag />
      <visible>true</visible>
      <history>10/8/2015|</history>
      <description />
    </Field>
  </Field>
</Material_NOI>';

 SELECT @XML.query('/Material_NOI/Field/Field')
 FOR XML PATH('Material_NOI')
```

### UPDATE: Same with table-data

You might use an *updateable CTE* like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(XmlColumn XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(N'<Material_NOI>
  <Field>
    <Field>
      <id>Type</id>
      <value>Initial</value>
      <tag />
      <visible>true</visible>
      <history>10/8/2015|</history>
      <description />
    </Field>
  </Field>
</Material_NOI>')
,(N'<Material_NOI>
  <Field>
    <Field>
      <id>Another id</id>
      <value>One more</value>
      <tag />
      <visible>false</visible>
      <history>10/8/2015|</history>
      <description />
    </Field>
  </Field>
</Material_NOI>');

WITH UpdateableCTE AS
(
    SELECT XmlColumn
          ,(SELECT XmlColumn.query('/Material_NOI/Field/Field') FOR XML PATH('Material_NOI'),TYPE) AS NewValue
    FROM @tbl
)
UPDATE UpdateableCTE SET XmlColumn=NewValue;

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

### UPDATE 2: Short version using FLWOR-query

```
UPDATE @tbl SET XmlColumn=XmlColumn.query(N'<Material_NOI>
                                            {
                                            for $f in /Material_NOI/Field/Field 
                                                return $f
                                            }
                                            </Material_NOI>');
```

Comment: Digging the FLWOR-query

Answer (score 2):

Using XQuery. This script is only going to work if all rows have the extra element. Make sure you make a copy of the table before you run this, you never know.

```sql
DECLARE @xml_table TABLE (x XML);
INSERT INTO @xml_table(x)VALUES(
'<Material_NOI>
  <Field>
  <Field>
    <id>Type</id>
    <value>Initial</value>
    <tag />
    <visible>true</visible>
    <history>10/8/2015|</history>
    <description />
    </Field>
    </Field>
 </Material_NOI>');

UPDATE
    @xml_table
SET
    x=x.query('<Material_NOI>{for $p in Material_NOI/Field/Field return $p}</Material_NOI>');

SELECT * FROM @xml_table;
```

Comment: This second I posted the same as UPDATE 2 :-) Anyway worth an upvote!

Comment: @Shnugo Yours too ;)